# Can't get an UPDATE with a SELECT (from another table) inside the SET parameter to work

Tags: sql, database, db2

The following query is giving me the error as seen below the query. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?  The inner select query works independently. The UPDATE works if I remove the select statement and replace with a number.
This is on db2 10.1.

```
UPDATE tdb2wccu.quot q
SET q.prr_ls_asmt_id = (
        SELECT prr_ls_asmt_id
        FROM final TABLE (
                INSERT INTO tdb2wcmd.prr_ls_asmt (creat_ts)
                VALUES (CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
                )
        )
where q.quot_id = 'befc0ec6a6af3c250ac8967f4fd7de56'
```

Error Message:

> [UPDATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -20165, SQL State:
>   428FL]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-20165, SQLSTATE=428FL, SQLERRMC=null,
>   DRIVER=3.63.75

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the error explanation in the manual?

Comment: @mustaccio Yeah, I looked it up but was unable to find any useful results.  If you find something, please share.

Answer (score 1):

You need to materialize the *data change table* before you can use it to update another table. One way to do it:

```
WITH t1 (newid) AS (
  SELECT prr_ls_asmt_id
  FROM final TABLE (
    INSERT INTO tdb2wcmd.prr_ls_asmt (creat_ts)
      VALUES (CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
  )
)
SELECT * FROM FINAL TABLE (
  UPDATE tdb2wccu.quot q
    SET q.prr_ls_asmt_id = (
      SELECT newid FROM t1
    )
  WHERE q.quot_id = 'befc0ec6a6af3c250ac8967f4fd7de56'
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're syntax is wrong. It should be

```
UPDATE tdb2wccu.quot q
SET q.prr_ls_asmt_id = prr_ls_asmt_id
FROM  Second_table
WHERE q1.quot_id = 'befc0ec6a6af3c250ac8967f4fd7de56
```

Comment: I think I disagree, but I also think I'm not completely following what you're saying. Could you post exactly what you think the code should look like?